# Store a integer and floating point number from a .dat file in C language

Tags: c, file, floating-point, scanf

Thanks for your kindly attention. I have a .dat file as the format below:

```
3 10.9
1 2.1
(empty line)
10 10.05
10 200
```

For each line, I want to store the first number(integer) into variable a, and store the second float number in variable

```
int c;
FILE *fp = fopen("supermarket.dat", "r");
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    int var1;
    float var2;
    fscanf(fp, "%d%f", &var1, &var2);
    printf("%d\n", var1);
    printf("%f\n", var2);
}
```

Now my program cause no error but all the data is wrong. The out in CMD is:

```
10
0.900000
1
2.10000
10
10.050000
10
200.0000000
10
200.000000
```

As you can see, some data is wrong, and it didn't print the empty line as 0 0. 
The correct output should be:

```
3 
10.9
1
2.1
0
0
10 
10.05
10
200
```

Comment: Your while loop makes no sense.

Comment: What is the run time error?

Comment: Mixing "%lf" and `float` is not a recipe for a happy life either

Comment: my loop make sure reading the file until to last data, didn't it?

Comment: @kdopen Sorry. After I change %lf to %f. No error. But still have some problem. Question Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading your input with 2 "concurrent" routines: `fgetc` (read a character) and `fscanf` (read formatted input). The `fgetc` part consumes the characters in a wrong way.

I suppose you called it because you wanted to check if end of file was reached but that's not the correct way to do it.

Do that instead:

```
while (1) {
    int var1;
    float var2;
    int nb_toks = fscanf(fp, "%d%f", &var1, &var2);
    if (nb_toks<2) break;
    printf("%d\n", var1);
    printf("%f\n", var2);
}
```

`fscanf` returns the number of items successfully read, so when you reach end of file, it returns 1 or 0, which means you can break out of the loop.

Comment: @alk: just edited it. Got blinded by the loop problem. kdopen already signaled it.

Comment: Thank you. Changing $lf to %f make the program run-able now. But the output in CMD is not correct.

Comment: forgot another `%lf`! what should it output?

Comment: Correct output edited in question. Thanks for your patient.

Comment: take my snippet and your file you'll get `3
10.900000
1
2.100000
10
10.050000
10
200.000000` as expected (just ran it). Or you just left the `fgetc` in your code.

Comment: I keep fgetc in my code. Because there're still further calculation after print the data. Therefore, I cannot use while(1). Besides, the expected output is shown in the question. It would consider empty line as two zero.

Comment: you have to choose between reading data with `fscanf` and `fgetc`. I'd say your question is answered. You may have a further problem, but that's another question to ask.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't saw your edited version answer. I change it to while(1) and successfully exit by return value of fscanf() now. Nice code.

Comment: Thanks. we did it :)